# how can I recieve this form in cart.php

Tags: php

```
$index = 1;
foreach($product['varieties'] as $variety){     
echo '<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price_' . $index . '" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '"  />';   
echo '<input name="size_' . $index . '" type="text" value="' . $variety['size']. '"  />';    $index++; 
}
```

if you can see This will have an index=1 and it will be incrementing where each iteration will be price_1, price_2, etc.and size_1,size_2. Now with a dynamic name="" input how can I receive in the cart.php when each name will be different?

it would be something like `$price= "'..',$_POST['price_']"`? well I have not idea how can I receive this name index from the cart.php url.

Thnank you.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question if you're hoping for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of string building the name like `size_1`, why not make the name like this `size[]`.

Then you can instantly access it like an array via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Look at alex's answer. It is better suited to the circumstances..

<strike>You could, at the end, add a hidden text box with the number of items (the $index value). and read it back</strike>

so after the loop add

```
echo '<input name="counter" type="hidden" value="' . $index. '"  />'
```

and when you try to read it, the first thing would be to read the `$POST['counter']` and then loop again from 1 to that value reading the `$POST['price_'.$loop_counter]`

Comment: I would prefer my method, instead of needing to keep track of a limit. What if someone (malicious) sends a higher number? More to check / debug / can go wrong.

Comment: That's OK - PHP has tonnes of little tricks to make web dev easier. This is one of the more useful ones.

Comment: If I understood is to take the counter off and use like everyone usually does it.

foreach($product['varieties'] as $variety){     
echo '<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '"  />';   
echo '<input name="size[]" type="hidden" value="' . $variety['size']. '"  />';     
} 

what about putting the type=hidden where only the scripter will be able to see it.

Comment: @Jona, As @alex mentioned, a user can alter the html even if it is hidden (so a malicious one can play tricks with the script.)..

Comment: @jona Putting it as hidden will take me about 2 seconds to circumvent.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the values with something like this:

```
$prices = preg_grep('/^price_\d+$/', $_POST);

foreach($prices as $P) {
   $idx = substr($p, 5); // extract the digits, which we know will be at position 5->end

   $size = $_POST['size_' . $idx];
   etc....
}
```

This assumes for that for every price_#, there's a corresponding size_#

Comment: You have an uppercase and lowercase p there.